# Initialize generic class via key word `self` in a class function

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class looks like this:

```
class MyContainer<T>  {
    required init() {}

    class func giveMeAContainer() -> MyContainer<Any?> {
        let container: MyContainer<Any?> = self()
        return container
    }
}
```

I got an error from the compiler, `'T' is not identical to 'Any?'`.

I have tried `self<Any?>()`, but obviously that is not a legal syntax.

So, can I initialize generic class via key word `self` in a class function?

--- Update 0

I want to return a value of type `MyContainer<Any?>` through this function.

But I don't want to override this function to return a `MyChildContainer<Any?>` when I create a subclass inherits `MyContainer<T>`.

And I believe `MyChildContainer<Any?>` is a `MyContainer<Any?>`. So this is logically legal.

--- Update 1

I realise what I want is

```
class func giveMeAContainer() -> Self<Any?> {
    return self<Any?>()
}
```

But obviously, this is not legal for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

Do you want to return `self()`?

```
class func giveMeAContainer() -> MyContainer<T> {
    let container: MyContainer<T> = self()
    return container
    // or
    // return self()
}
```

Do you want to return `MyContainer<Any?>`

```
class func giveMeAContainer() -> MyContainer<Any?> {
    let container: MyContainer<Any?> = MyContainer<Any?>()
    return container 
    // or
    // return MyContainer<Any?>()
}
```

Comment: Thx for reply. I wrote down what I want in the update.